# How to render ".vm" files

Tags: java, tomcat, velocity

I'm trying to render some **.vm** files using velocity engine on centos7. I have downloaded **velocity-engine-core-2.0.jar** but I don't know what should I do with this jar file and how should I configure tomcat using that to be able to render .vm files. I don't have much java knowledge, just need to render this views so I can make some changes in the style sheets.

Here is my assets structure:

```
/css/
/images/
/views/ (.vm files are here)
/file1.properties
/file2.properties
```

Comment: I'm thinking "too broad."  You should try Google before asking these sorts of questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=velocity+template+examples&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: please paste your web.xml file and other mapping.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277263/how-do-i-install-and-use-apache-velocity/10280506#10280506), which details the setup of a webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to keep a mapping like below in web.xml:

```
 <web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.vm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```